# Generating a Signed APK "Keystore was tampered with"

Tags: android, google-play

I am trying to push an update to my app, but when I am trying to build the APK, I get

> Failed to read key from store: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

I am certain that the Key Alias and password are correct. Is there a way to fix this without having to generate a whole new keystore? From my understanding, if I generate a new keystore I can't push updates to the app that is already in the playstore

Comment: Are you using Android Studio?

Comment: Your understanding is correct. The password dialog allows for copy-paste so try copying it from notepad where you can see for sure the pass is right.

Comment: @MichaelLiberman Yes I am using Android Studio

Comment: @poss I have tried copying and pasting from notepad where I made sure I saved the correct values and it is the same result

Comment: Then try going to Build -> Generate signed APK -> Next -> and press the "..." near key alias. Maybe you will see the proper alias you used.

Comment: @MichaelLiberman when I go there I get a dialog with the same message instead of having it in the messages log

Comment: Then try running "keytool -v -list -keystore .keystore -alias yourAlias" to make sure you are using proper alias.

Comment: @MichaelLiberman So when I do that, I get Alias does not exist and then a small stack dump

Comment: Then it means you are using a different alias than the one you entered for the keystore. You probably entered a password for this command, so if you got "Alias <yourAlias> does not exist", it means the password is correct but the alias should be different

Comment: re-run keytool without the alias parameter `keytool -v -list -keystore .keystore`.  It will list the aliases stored in the keystore

Comment: @iagreen that worked thank you. Do you want to put that as an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: @MichaelLiberman Diagnosed the issue, I'll let him post the answer.

Comment: @iagreen, thank you and lots of respect. Your comment was my next proposal but you beat me to it ;)

Comment: I'm getting this error after switching to `com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.3.0-alpha5`. I know 100% that my passwords and alias are correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is an issue of forgetting the alias you used for your keystore, you can list the aliases for your keystore using the following command:

```
keytool -v -list -keystore .keystore
```